# Nodejs fs.readfile vs new buffer binary

Tags: node.js

I have a situation where I receive a base64 encoded image, decode it, then want to use it in some analysis activity.

I can use Buffer to go from base64 to binary but i seem to be unable to use that output as expected (as an image).

The solution now is to convert to binary, write it to a file, then read that file again. The FS output can be used as an image but this approach seems a bit inefficient and additional steps as i would expect the buffer output to also be a usable image as it has the same data?

my question, is how does the fs.readfile output differ from the buffer output? And is there a way i can use the buffer output as i would the fs output?

Buffer from a base64 string:

```
var bin = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64').toString('binary');
```

Read a file

```
var bin = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg');
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you need to provide an encoding for readFileSync? fs.readFileSync('image.jpg', 'binary')

Comment: I don't think so, the bin from fs.readfilesync is working as expected. its the bin from new buffer that isnt doing what i would assume.